# How to test the value of LimitRequestFieldSize in Apache 2.4

Tags: centos, web-server, apache-2.4, httpd.conf, centos7

I would like to test the value of LimitRequestFieldSize in Apache 2.4.

I have tried setting it and was wondering if there was a straightforward way of calling its value from apache or testing it via a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way to test it is by sending an [actual request field](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) of just below the size you picked and then just above the size you picked to see if you get an error response.

As for it being implemented, if you have restarted apache, it should work.

Comment: How would you create such a large request artificially?

Comment: Well how large are we talking? The program I linked is an example of programs you could use to build a request and send it to the server. Rule of the thumb though, is that one letter is about 1 byte, so for 1kB you type 1000 letters. But bear in mind that the request formulation itself also takes up a few hundred bytes. Alternatively you can also just build a PHP or other programming language script, that issues the request dynamically.

Comment: Glad to be of service! :)